# How can I ignore a specific NuGet package to restore?

Tags: tfs, build, nuget, restore, ignore

For some reasons I don't want NuGet to restore specific packages. Is there a way to give arguments like ignore [package]?

The way I use now is to 'continue on error', but the downside I get is getting only partially succeeding builds.

[build restore nuget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwGoW.png)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DanielMann Because 1 of the NuGet packages is a 'self made' NuGet package by the company I work. So the server, which provides this self made package, is not available from the build server. In the future we will move the NuGet service to the build service, but for now I wanted to know if there is a way to ignore that specific NuGet package.

Comment: Add a package source where the package is located to the NuGet.config so it can restore as part of the build process.

Comment: @HhK Did you try the answer below and do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

This task doesn't support to ignore packages. It will restore all packages that defined in the **package.config** file. I suggest that you delete your custom package in the package.config file and check in to TFS. When you need this package, add it in your local place.

If you don't want to delete it in package.config file, to solve your error, you must **check in** a [NuGet.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) file and specify the path to it in this task if you are using a package source other than NuGet.org.

[image]

In the future, if you want to move your Nuget server, I suggest that you could use TFS server as a nuget server directly. You could upload your custom packages to TFS nuget feed. For more details, please refer to this document: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started-nuget. This for TFS 2017 and upper version.